# Oracle Insert Missing Records

Tags: oracle

I have written a package for building a reporting table.  The simplified code for the function I am testing follows:

```
function do_build return integer is
  V_RESULT     PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  cursor all_entities is
    select e.id_number
    from entity e
  ;
BEGIN 
c_count := 0; -- this variable is declared at the package level outside of this function
for rec in all_entities LOOP
  BEGIN
    insert into reporting (
      select *
      from table(get_report_data(rec.id_number))
    );
    c_count := c_count + 1;
    if MOD(c_count, 1000) = 0 Then
      -- record status to table
      commit;
    end if;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- record exception to table
  END;
END LOOP;
return V_RESULT;
END;
```

A little background: get_report_data is a function that returns a dataset with all of the input entity's reporting data.

About 1000 records out of 1 million are missing from the "reporting" table when the build completes.  No exceptions are thrown and other than the missing records, everything appears to have been successful (function returns 0 to caller).

When I run the get_report_data for the entity records that do not have their reporting data recorded, the records show up fine.  In fact, I can do an adhoc "insert into reporting (select * from table(get_reporting_data(missing_id))" and the information will be inserted.

Why would these records be skipped/fail to insert?  Should I be looping a different way?  Any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only committing every 1000 rows.  You're not committing the last batch.  Add a commit after the END LOOP;

```
BEGIN 
c_count := 0; -- this variable is declared at the package level outside of   this function
for rec in all_entities LOOP
 BEGIN
   insert into reporting (
     select *
     from table(get_report_data(rec.id_number))
   );
   c_count := c_count + 1;
   if MOD(c_count, 1000) = 0 Then
     -- record status to table
     commit;
   end if;
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- record exception to table
 END;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;  -- <-- Add this commit to pick up last few records
return V_RESULT;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can this be a concurrency issue? If the records are committed in the ENTITY table while you loop is running they won't be processed.

BTW: Using WHEN OTHERS in this way is asking for trouble.

BTW2: Why not simply use:

```
INSERT INTO reporting
SELECT rep.*
FROM entity e
CROSS JOIN table(get_report_data(e.id_number)) rep;
```

Comment: Interesting.  I will toy with this method to see if it may yield faster insert.  I assume it will.  I don't necessarily need status updates if the performance is significantly faster.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also, do you care to elaborate why using WHEN OTHERS is bad form?

Comment: With WHEN OTHERS you will catch any errors - not just the ones that you expect. So problems with network connectivity, the database being shutdown etc. which are completely unrelated to the row you are processing will get caught.

Comment: @nrg This will definitely yield better performance and it's the style I usually use.  But I still use cursors when I'm also generating audit trails or status reports. If you have a performance issue and want to use cursors, I'd research bulk collect.